# What is the project parameters for SFML Network?

Tags: networking, chat, sfml

I have simple SFML Network code of chat:

https://github.com/4EFI/Online-Chat/blob/main/Online%20Chat/OnlineChat.cpp

But it don't compile in Visual Studio. For graphics apps I set next project parameters:
`C/C++ -> Preprocessor -> Defines of preprocessor -> SFML_DYNAMIC`

```
Linker -> Input -> ... ->

sfml-graphics-d.lib
sfml-window-d.lib
sfml-system-d.lib
sfml-audio-d.lib
(for Debug)
```

and

```
sfml-graphics.lib
sfml-window.lib
sfml-system.lib
sfml-audio.lib
(for Release).
```

What I must to do to SFML Network can to compile?

I want to write a simple Internet-Chat with SFML Network.

Answer (score 0):

I can to find the solve:

```
Linker -> Input ->
sfml-network.lib
sfml-network-d.lib
```